# Definition of 'escuela' and 'colegio'

Tags: selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, definiciones

Spanish has two generic words for *school*: **escuela** and **colegio**. I have heard different explanations for what phases of schooling each word refers to. For example, I've been told that *colegio* refers only to high school and also that it can describe any school all that way down to kindergarten or first grade.

Other school words are more obvious: *primaria* means primary school, *secundaria* means secondary school, *universidad* means university. But for *escuela* and *colegio*, what grade or age range do they most commonly refer to? Are there any major regional differences from the norm?

Comment: I think several of the English words for schools and colleges also very their meanings quite a bit by region.

Comment: NB. Se puede encontrar tambien la abreviacion 'cole' cuando se dice de colegios.

Comment: Don't forget *facultad*, as in the School of Business, Art, Sciences, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am adding this summary following what was discussed in [Juntemos en respuestas wiki las respuestas cortas específicas de regiones / Let's use community wiki to summarize set of short region specific answers](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2483/1674). Feel free to edit to add the term used in your country or region.

---

| Country | Usage |
| --- | --- |
| Argentina | **escuela**: primary school **colegio**: secondary school |
| Chile | **escuela** (1): public primary school (1° básico to 8° básico). **escuela** (2): higher education institute, part of a university or college (ex.: Escuela de Arquitectura de la Universidad X). **liceo**: public secondary school (I medio to IV medio). **colegio** (1): private school, primary and secondary (1° básico to IV medio). **colegio** (2): generic school ("Se acabaron las vacaciones, de vuelta al colegio"). Sometimes it used to make an economic or social distinction: "escuela" and "liceo" are free, "colegio" is paid. |
| Colombia | **escuela**: primary school, generally a public one **colegio**: all institutions, both primary and secondary Both words are also used for some universities names. An university covers the "college" time plus "university" time, |
| Cuba | There is no difference between *ir a la escuela* and *ir al colegio*. Both refer to the same institution. *Colegio* es used way less frequently than *escuela*. |
| España | **escuela**: school **colegio**: primary and secondary school **instituto**: prep-school All of them + *superior*: college |
| Guatemala | **escuela**: public school **colegio**: private school Both words could also refer to elementary or high-school level. |
| Mexico | **escuela**: school, usually grade school level (but in informal speech can be used to refer to *any* educational setting) **colegio**: college (this could be ambiguous -- safer choice is universidad) **escuela secundaria**: high school **universidad** or **uni** for short: university **secundaria**: corresponds to the US junior high or middle school **preparatoria**, or **prepa** for short: corresponds to US "high school" **Colegio técnico**: a college that teaches a special trade without taking all the extras needed for a higher degree. |

Comment: Cuba: no hay diferencia. Ir a la escuela, ir al colegio. Se refiere a la misma institución. La palabra colegio se usa aunque en mucho menor medida que escuela.

Comment: I completely disagree in the Spain part. Both "escuela" and "colegio" refer to the same thing: primary school and/or kindergarten. The next stage is "instituto". This is like this unless you're in a private school in which they have both toghether. So "escuela" and "colegio" would be valid from 3 to 11 years old (except the private schools having it joined, which are until 16). Standard ages are: kindergarten (3→5); primary school (5→11) and secondary school (instituto) (12→16).

Comment: So the difference between "escuela" and "colegio" is just "none" in Spain. If you want more nuances, "escuela" sounds more childish, so it's more likely to be used at the beginning, and also by moms and all that. Most children like to use "colegio", as it sounds less "childish".

Comment: @FGSUZ this is a wiki answer, feel free to [edit] to improve it!

Answer (score 10):

Every country has a different usage, and sometimes you can't even trust those conventions.

In Argentina, *escuela* **usually** means primary school, and *colegio* **usually** means secondary school, in both cases assuming no additional context. But primary school students can refer to their school as *colegio* too, and many secondary schools have *escuela* in their names.

In other words, the only way to be sure is to be specific.

Comment: +1 I'd say that in Argentina (and anywhere) the difference is quite vague. http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=674369

Answer (score 6):

En Colombia, el término "escuela" (referido al sitio en donde se instruye a los niños) se utiliza sobre todo para las instituciones públicas de educación primaria, aunque (dependiendo del contexto) puede usarse "escuela" también para una institución privada de educación primaria. El término "colegio" se utiliza para todas las instituciones, indistintamente de su caracter público o privado, de educación primaria y secundaria.

Aunque usualmente se usan "escuela" y "colegio" para instituciones de educación primaria o secundaria, existen universidades que en su nombre utilizan las palabras "escuela" o "colegio", por ejemplo la [Escuela Colombiana de Ingeniería](https://www.escuelaing.edu.co/es/) o el [Colegio Mayor de Nuestra Señora del Rosario](http://www.urosario.edu.co/).

Answer (score 3):

As far as I have seen it used in Spain:

- *escuela* — school, as generic term to describe any type of teaching institution (even stuff like eg. cooking courses);
- *colegio* — primary & secondary school;
- *instituto* — prep-school;
- *[escuela|colegio|instituto] superior* — college;

Answer (score 2):

In Mexican Spanish, the word "escuela" is a generic term for school, usually grade school level, "colegio" means college, high school is called "escuela secundaria", and a university is called "universidad". We also have "colegio tecnico" = Technical College, as of a college that teaches a special trade without taking all the extras needed for a higher degree.

Answer (score 2):

In Guatemala, for some reason, the distinction is whether it's public or private education:

- **Escuela** is a public school.
- **Colegio** is a private school.
- **Universidad** is a university, regardless of funding source.

In both cases, it could refer to elementary or high-school level.  We don't really have the concept of a "middle school", except in American-style schools.

Answer (score 0):

In Puerto Rico, we have definitions of schools by level and age-range.

- **Escuela** means "school", age-range doesn't matter.
- **Escuela primaria** means "primary school".  Usually, it ranges from Kindergarten to 5th grade.
- **Escuela intermedia** means "middle school".
- **Escuela secundaria** and **liceo** both mean "high school".
- **Colegio** refers to "college".  It also means "university".  This identifies an institution of higher-level education.
- **Universidad** is a synonym to colegio.
- COLEGIO IS NOT HIGH SCHOOL!

P.S. I'm Puerto Rican.

Comment: DRAE: ***colegio** 1. m. Establecimiento de enseñanza para niños y jóvenes.*  Understand that PR is not the only place that speaks Spanish and usage varies on these things quite substantially.

Comment: He is Puerto Rican but I'm Colombian and here Colegio IS High School.

Comment: In Bolivia: "Escuela" is for elementary up to grade 5, "colegio" from grade 6 to grade 12, there is no "escuela intermedia", "Universidad" for university. There is no college as it is the US/Canada. Trades are called "instituto" or "tecnológico". I'm Bolivian ;). 
pd: I'm surprised that in Canada they even call school to university or college.

Answer (score 0):

Durante la colonia española, siglos 17 al 19, la educación que ahora llamamos primaria y secundaria no existía y la enseñanza era de carácter privado y personalizado, y por lo tanto solo al alcance de personas con buen nivel económico.
Las instituciones educativas que inicialmente se fundaron en las colonias españolas en América fueron los "[Colegios Mayores](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colegio_mayor)", que eran para formación universitaria de grados mayores (licenciatura y doctorado).
Cuando la educación empezó a masificarse la palabra "colegio" fue extendida para cubrir lo que ahora son los grados de primaria y secundaria.