# Best way to translate 'uneducated', meaning lacking formal schooling

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, vocabulario, uso-de-palabras

Generally the Spanish word `maleducado` more often means `rude`, rather than `unschooled`. In light of this, how would one describe someone who is `polite and intelligent`, but has `never been formally schooled` and hence is ignorant of most technical subjects? I looked it up on [SpanishDict](http://www.spanishdict.com/) and found these:

> - *Falto de educación*
> - *sin instrucción*
> - *ignorante*
> - *inculto(a)*

What are the precise differences in implication between each of these? Are there any other ways to translate 'uneducated' in the manner I've described? Which seems to most closely fit the definition of someone who is very capable of learning, but has never been taught very much?

(A little more digging didn't produce the fine distinction I was looking for, so I decided to come here :)

Comment: maybe you can add to the list "analfabeto" (someone who can't read or write because he has never gone to school).

Comment: Si se trata de falta de estudios en un tema o materia en particular, a menudo se emplea la palabra "**lego**" [Lego. Definición Real Academia](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=N5D53vo)

Answer (score 8):

In a general way I would use **"Sin estudios"** and if I want to make it more exact:

- Sin estudios básicos (uneducated)
- Sin estudios secundarios (without High school education)
- Sin estudios universitarios (without university education)

Comment: +1; Still, I wouldn't assume that everyone understands that "college" is the proper translation for "universidad"; please see http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/432/definition-of-escuela-and-colegio A better way of putting "sin estudios universitarios" in English is, in my opinion, "with no tertiary education" or even "with no university education.

Answer (score 4):

First off, since you will be commenting on the level of someone's education, you'll usually want to be cautious in the words you choose, since no one would like their level of intelligence to be made fun of! ;)

Anyways, since you are looking for a *polite* way to express this, I probably wouldn't lean in the direction of `ignorante` or `inculto`. These words *aren't* totally rude per se, but they might come off as being a little too blunt. You could probably get away using them in a joking or playful manner, but caution is still advised.  Other words that could probably fall into this category might include `bruto` (*brute*), and `necio` (roughly: *uneducated fool*.)

Now, `falto(a) de educación` would probably work, but it could also be interpreted in a way similar to `maleducado`, that is `rude`. It would really depend on the context.

In my humble opinion, I think that a good (and unambigious) way to express `the lack of education`, would be to use an expression meaning `without`. In this case the preposition `sin` or a negative of the verb `tener` work well. These patterns also allow you to specify the type of education a person lacks (e.g. `escuela secundaria` (high school), `colegio` (college), etc.)

For Example:

> - Ella está sin colegio.
> - Ella no tiene (un título del) colegio.
>
> *She doesn't have a college education.*

That more-or-less should cover all the basic and general expressions that would be used. In general, the same principles that you would use to choose how you'd express this in English will apply here. Just try to be sensitive and smile. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: +1. Another example would be "Ella no tiene estudios."

Comment: Spanish "colegio" is not a good translation for English "college", at least in Spain and other regions; see http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/432/definition-of-escuela-and-colegio @Laura 's answer on this page avoids this issue and is, IMHO, a much better answer.

Comment: @CesarGon I understand your concern, but in such a trivial case as this, I doubt it really makes that much of a difference. The point of my answer was to try to emphasize patterns of "without" (e.g. `sin` & `no tiene`) and @Laura's answer does so as well. I simply chose a word that came to mind quickly and that I would typically use in these types of context. Even if the word isn't 100% universal, I think the point still gets across. That said, you may always edit my answers to help improve them... :)

Answer (score 2):

A polite word often used for people lack of academic education is `iletrado`.
The RAE dictionary defines it as a synonym of `analfabeto`, but usually, analfabeto is intended to describe someone who can't read/write, or lacks of the most basic education skills.
Iletrado sounds less rude.

Comment: At least in Spain, I'm sure that many people wouldn't even know what "iletrado" means, because it's not a word widely used by an average native speaker.

Comment: @Javi: Well, I have never found with this situation. And usually is taken as less offensive as the analfabeto alternative.

Comment: I disagree with both of you; with Javi, because `iletrado` is a very common word, and with Tomas, because `iletrado` is not an appropriate word to refer to someone that lacks formal schooling, which is what the question is about. I would even argue that calling someone `iletrado`, unless you are referring to a person that can't read and write, is a very rude word to use. For example: `Eres un iletrado` is just as rude as calling someone ignorant: `Eres un ignorante`. The author of this blog: http://gazapping.blogspot.com/ never finished grammar school and you couldn't call him `iletrado`

Comment: @Icarus I'm referring just to Spain not in general. It may be used widely by the average speaker in other countries.

Answer (score 1):

In case of formal education, alternative word you can use instead of `educación` is `formación` (it does have slightly different meaning that "education", it's rarely used in context of primary schools, and it's also used for "professional training").

Thus when talking about a person who isnot qualified for the job because of lack of eg. college education, you can say:

*Le falta la formación para este puesto*

Answer (score 1):

> How would one describe someone who is polite and intelligent, but has
>   never been formally schooled and hence is ignorant of most technical
>   subjects?

Some choices are:

- Falto de formación técnica
- Falto de educación formal

`Maleducado` is used to refer to someone that lacks good manners. You can have a post doctorate degree in astrophysics from Princeton and still be a `maleducado`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some gentle ways of describing such a person, that work well in Mexico:

> No tiene mucha escuela
>
> No pudo hacer mucha escuela
>
> No ha hecho mucha escuela

*[She hasn't had much schooling / She wasn't able to get very far along with formal education]*